# Can inline images be referenced from a different message in a thread?

Tags: email, mime

My research through the RFC says that you can reference inline content from other mail parts using the `cid:` token.  I also know that you can use the `mid:` token in a similar for message-ID.  When referencing a message-ID, you can reference mail parts of another message by doing `mid:messageId/contentId`, contentId being a valid contentId in the target message.

I'm leaning towards no, inline images (or other inline content) can't be referenced and displayed in entirely different messages.  But if that's true, I can't piece together what the purpose of using `mid:` is.

A simple visualization of what I'm imagining is this:

Given a multipart message with an html body and inline image... our cid reference would look like:

`<img src="cid:abcd-i-am-a-content-id">`

This assumes we do in fact have a multipart/related with a mail part that has some valid image payload with a matching content-ID.

What if we were replying to this original message, can I do something like:

`<img src="mid:original-message-id/abcd-i-am-a-content-id">` to inline this resource that would presumably be accessible by the client's mail store that belongs to the recipient assuming all other normal threading rules are followed?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to do that and expect it to work.

Even "mid:" won't work in most clients.